# REST API for yii2, the authenticator (HttpBearerAuth) is not working on server

Tags: yii2, restful-authentication

I've just created a project for working with REST API (using yii2 framework).
All issues of REST API is working really cool on localhost. But when bringing the project on server (also the same database is taken by), the authorization is not available. Now I'm using "yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth"

Inside the model "implements IdentityInterface",  there's finding-token function "findIdentityByAccessToken" that's so simple, the "validateAuthKey" function is returning always true; see below:

```
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null){  
    return static::findOne(["token" => $token]);  
}

public function validateAuthKey($token)    
{ 
    return true;  
}
```

See any pictures: 
https://www.flickr.com/photos/40158620@N03/20701523349/in/dateposted-public/
Anyone can have some experience on this problem, can you tell me how to solve it? Thanks for your kindness.

- Note:
- The project, I'm following https://github.com/NguyenDuyPhong/yii2_advanced_api_phong (It works **fine on localhost**; I also deployed exactly the project on my server, it raised the same problem )
- To make sure that the server is configured right: I created 2 actions, 1 is authorized, another is not. I checked unauthorized action, it works very well. =======>
- actionView is not authorized => getting API info. is ok
- actionIndex is authorized by "yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth" => FAIL

Comment: Does your server use Nginx or Apache?

Comment: Here is my server configuration: http://loyalty.gikapp.com/frontend/web/requirements.php  
+ Web Server: Apache 2.4.16 (Unix) 
+ OpenSSL 1.0.1e
+ PHP 5.5.27

Comment: Chịu rồi, trước từng gặp vấn đề với NginX còn apache thì chưa bao giờ :D

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me your solution on NginX? it may be useful for me. @@

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: I got the  same error if anyone got a solution please share. @Fittersman

Answer (score 6):

In my case the Problem was that the server removes Authorization Header 
I needed to add this to .htaccess

```
 SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Comment: For the sake of SEO: This is required if you use Plesk, because Plesk's default is to remove Authorization Headers.

Comment: I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72964870/6854117) related to it. Can you pl see it?

Comment: @Moeez sorry I don't work with Yii framework anymore since 2017 I don't believe that I have enough knowledge now to answer you

Comment: Very useful info here

Answer (score 0):

HttpBearerAuth used `$user->loginByAccessToken` to authorize [see](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/223b0bea5dfb63086354e9e3a7f94fc244d37b4e/framework/web/User.php#L262)

`validateAuthKey` used by `"loginByCookie"`(and it seems that in this case not used)

Try to use `QueryParamAuth` for test purposes (it's easier to test)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with a bit more detail? I'm not quite sure that I understand what you'd like me to try.

Comment: Probably should to make a comment, not an answer. 
But nevertheless, wanted to get across two thoughts:
 1: validateAyutnkey is not used in this case. 
 2. try to use QueryParamAuth and authorize that way .../app-user-tokens?access_token=token. Will there be a 401 error?

Comment: I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72964870/6854117) related to it. Can you pl see it?