# Yii2 rest api with bearer auth

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I created the api structure/config and it works but now i need to set it up with bearer authentication and every GET request i send to the api (with Authentication Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXX) gives me a 401 error:

```
{"name":"Unauthorized","message":"Your request was made with invalid credentials.","code":0,"status":401,"type":"yii\\web\\UnauthorizedHttpException"}
```

Sorry about the length of this question with all snippets but i tried several changes, read all what i found here about this with no success and im starting to lose control on this. What could i be missing?

My app uses the advanced template with the next folder structure (the same as in all howtos ive read):

```
> -api
>     --config
>       --main.php
>       --params.php
>     --modules
>       --v1
>        --controllers
>          --OrdersController.php
>        --models
>          --Orders.php
>        --Module.php
>     --web
>        --index.php
> -backend
> -common
> -frontend...
```

api/config/main.php

```
<?php

$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php')
    //require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),    
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
        ]
    ],
    'components' => [        
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'enableSession' => false,
            'loginUrl' =>'',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                    'controller' => 'v1/countries',
                    'tokens' => [
                        '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                    ]

                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                    'controller' => 'v1/orders',
                    'tokens' => [
                        '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                    ]

                ]
            ],        
        ]
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

api/config/params.php

```
<?php
return [
    'adminEmail' => 'admin@domain.com',
];
```

api/modules/v1/Module.php

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'api\modules\v1\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        \Yii::$app->user->enableSession = false;
    }
}
```

api/modules/v1/controllers/OrdersController.php

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\auth\CompositeAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
use yii\filters\auth\QueryParamAuth;

class OrdersController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Orders';

    public function actions()       // Just read only rest api
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['delete'], $actions['create'], $actions['update']);
        return $actions;
    }

    public function behaviors() {

        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['contentNegotiator']['formats']['text/html'] = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            //'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            //'class' => QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

common/models/User.php

```
<?php
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\NotSupportedException;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * User model
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property integer $status
 * @property integer $created_at
 * @property integer $updated_at
 * @property string $password write-only password
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    const STATUS_DELETED = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 10;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE],
            ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return static::findOne(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        //throw new NotSupportedException('"findIdentityByAccessToken" is not implemented.');
        return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        return static::findOne(['username' => $username, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by password reset token
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByPasswordResetToken($token)
    {
        if (!static::isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return static::findOne([
            'password_reset_token' => $token,
            'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if password reset token is valid
     *
     * @param string $token password reset token
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isPasswordResetTokenValid($token)
    {
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }

        $timestamp = (int) substr($token, strrpos($token, '_') + 1);
        $expire = Yii::$app->params['user.passwordResetTokenExpire'];
        return $timestamp + $expire >= time();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->auth_key;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
    }

    /**
     * Generates new password reset token
     */
    public function generatePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '_' . time();
    }

    /**
     * Removes password reset token
     */
    public function removePasswordResetToken()
    {
        $this->password_reset_token = null;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467948/1823209) i was able to find what was happening. Just added

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

to api/web/.htaccess and it works

Is this the best approach?

Comment: not working in my case :(

Comment: I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72964870/6854117) related to it. Can you pl see it?